# Read Guid stored as binary from Sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite

In my C# program I need to use DataReader to retrieve Guids from Sqlite database where they are stored as bianries.

I tried the following code but it failed to convert the ClassId to Guid.

```
using (IDataReader dataReader = DatabaseConnection.ExecuteReader(_getFileCountByClassCommand, new Dictionary<string, object>()))
         {
            while(dataReader.Read())
            {

               string str = Convert.ToString(dataReader["ClassId"]);
               fileCount.Add(new Guid(str), (int)dataReader["FileCount"]);
            }
         }
```

Anybody knows how to do this? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [SqlDataReader.GetGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getguid.aspx)

You don't need to convert to **string** and back again to a **Guid**